# How to search JSON in R?

Tags: r, json, parsing

So I basically have a data structure in JSON, with the following organization:

```
{
  object1: {
    "sub_object1": {
      "attribute1": ["potato", "asparagus", "celery"],
      "attribute2": ["ostrich", "pelican"]
    },
    "sub_object2": {
    }
  },
  object2: {
  }
}
```

So I'm reading this in using `rjson` and trying to search the structure. So far I have something like this:

```
for (entry in json_obj) {
  if (grepl(query, entry$sub_object1$attribute1, fixed=TRUE)) {
    ... Record result object here ...
  } else if (grepl(query, entry$sub_object1$attribut2, fixed=TRUE)) {
    ... Record result object here ...
  }
}
```

Basically, if I searched for "potato", I'd like it to return something like the following:

```
{
  object1: {
    "matched_string": "potato",
    "matched_property": attribute1,
    "full_entry": entry
  }
}
```

Python is my native language (I'm using R for the R Shiny frontend), so I never imagined JSON manipulation to be this difficult! Any help would be very, very much appreciated!

Comment: One thing which has helped me a ton with `JSON` in `R` is using the R Studio object explorer. If you look in the Environment tab and click on the `JSON` object you are interested in, it will pop up in the viewer window. You can then expand/collapse it and click on an element to see the code required to extract that element. More info [here](https://blog.rstudio.com/2017/08/22/rstudio-v1-1-preview-object-explorer/).

Answer (score 0):

Reading in a json file in R will turn it into a list of lists (of lists...). You can then recurse through that nested list to return a similar structure of returned values.

For example:

```
# it's recommended to use jsonlite as the json parser
json <- jsonlite::fromJSON('{
  "object1": {
    "sub_object1": {
      "attribute1": ["potato", "asparagus", "celery"],
      "attribute2": ["ostrich", "pelican"]
    },
    "sub_object2": {
    }
  },
  "object2": {
  }
}')

find <- function(obj, string)
{
    lapply(obj, function(x) {
        if(is.list(x))
            find(x, string)
        else grepl(string, x, fixed=TRUE)
    })
}

jsonlite::toJSON(find(json, "potato"), auto_unbox=TRUE, pretty=TRUE)
#{
#  "object1": {
#    "sub_object1": {
#      "attribute1": [true, false, false],
#      "attribute2": [false, false]
#    },
#    "sub_object2": {}
#  },
#  "object2": {}
#}
```

I'll assume that once you've got the json above, you can use your favourite language to transform it into the format you want (which isn't fully detailed in your question).